# How to disable all checkbox with use of foreach in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, foreach

I want to disable all checkbox when click all 'select all'.

How is this possible using jQuery?

**JavaScript:**

Here `categories[]` is name of checkbox which is in foreach loop

```
function checkAll(source) {
    checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('categories[]');

    for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
        //checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
        checkboxes[i].disabled = source.disabled;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't need using `forech` to do that.

Comment: what problem you get ?

Comment: using this javascript ...all checkbox not disable....can you solve this javascript? If solved...then i will implement javascript.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function uncheckAll() {
  $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
}

function disableAll() {
  $('input:checkbox').attr('disabled','true');
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" checked>A<br/>
<input type="checkbox" checked>B<br/>
<input type="checkbox">C<br/>
<input type="checkbox" checked>D<br/>
<input type="checkbox">E<br/>
<button onclick="uncheckAll()">Uncheck all</button>
<button onclick="disableAll()">Disable all</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `prop('disabled', true)`

```js
$('#mainChk').on('click', function(){
  var categories = $('.categories');
  categories.prop('disabled', !categories.prop('disabled'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="mainChk" type="checkbox" > Main
<input type="checkbox" class="categories"> First
<input type="checkbox" class="categories"> Second
<input type="checkbox" class="categories"> Third
```

Comment: Thanks @Suren Srapyan

Comment: @RohanHapani if this helps, you can accept this to help others find it easily

Answer (score 0):

Give all your checkbox a class (ex: class='ck').

Then :

```
$('.ck').each(function(){
$(this).prop('disabled', true);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you.

```
     <input type="checkbox" checked>A<br/>
     <input type="checkbox" checked>B<br/>
     <input type="checkbox">C<br/>
     <input type="checkbox" checked>D<br/>
     <input type="checkbox">E<br/>
     <button class="disableAll">Disable all</button>

     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".disableAll").click(function(){
      $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){
      $(this).prop('disabled', true);
   })
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Ajay Malhotra

Answer (score 0):

you can enable disable checkboxes with jquery like this.

```
$('#checkAll:checkbox').change(function () {
    if($(this).attr("checked")) $('input:checkbox').attr('checked','checked');
    else $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
});
```

Have a look at this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xHCwJ/).

Comment: Thnx @Asim Shahzad